# How to use smartglass in context of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, xbox360

In the context of Windows-8, I keep seeing mentions of SmartGlass feature.

What is SmartGlass, How do we go about using it or is there any good blog post detailing about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SmartGlass app will essentially enable people to use their phones, tablets and PCs as “second screens” and remote controllers for the Xbox 360.

- [Microsoft posts SmartGlass walkthrough, launching alongside Windows 8](http://www.techspot.com/news/50576-microsoft-posts-smartglass-walkthrough-launching-alongside-windows-8.html)
- [Xbox SmartGlass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_SmartGlass)

Answer (score 1):

SmartGlass is an XBOX Companion application, run on various devices (Phone, Tablet, or PC) to remotely control an XBOX.

The best description of it is actually at the XBOX SmartGlass site: http://www.xbox.com/en-US/smartglass